# Missing import in graphqldgs springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, graphql, netflix-dgs

I have installed and setup graphqldgs on a spring boot project following the guide here: https://netflix.github.io/dgs/getting-started/

When i try to write a test case - following the guide here: https://netflix.github.io/dgs/query-execution-testing/ - I am unable to import one of the values, as shown below

`import com.netflix.graphql.dgs.autoconfig.DgsAutoConfiguration`

I cannot locate DgsAutoConfiguration. The only thing i have is an asterix (*) after dot notation below:

`import com.netflix.graphql.dgs.autoconfig.`

I have these graphqldgs pom dependencies below:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.netflix.graphql.dgs</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.netflix.graphql.dgs</groupId>
  <artifactId>graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies</artifactId>
  <!-- The DGS BOM/platform dependency. This is the only place you set version of DGS -->
  <version>4.9.16</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in IntelliJ. Installing the Kotlin plugin [1] fixed it.

[1] https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Comment: worked! thanks!